# How to use isolate to open socket and push notification

Tags: sockets, flutter, dart, notifications

How to use isolate to open a socket and push notifications even when the app is terminated ?

Comment: You can't. An isolate is a child process of the app's process. If the app isn't running, then neither is the isolate.

Comment: yes, that's what i figured out, thanks you ^^